# How to code for graph database

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to graph database. I am badly confused how to code for it.
Either by Cypher Query Language or from java.And what is the use neoeclipse.
If i have to code from java and then which packages to import?
If Cypher then how to connect it with java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with the [neo4j tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials.html).

Briefly, cypher is a query language.  Once you have data in graphs, you can query it with cypher just like you would use SQL for a regular database.  You can also use java, but I don't recommend doing it via java unless you have a requirement that indicates that cypher isn't suitable.   Cypher will be easier at first, and will do most of what you want with no java code at all.

Neoeclipse is a [tool to view, edit, and explore databases](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse).  I've never used it though, as the web front end that comes with neo4j is usually enough for me.

If you want to get started writing java programs with neo4j, [start here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/java).  If you want to write cypher queries that run in a java program, you can [find those documentation items here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html).